# My stacked barchart keeps becoming invisible

Tags: python, matplotlib

I don't know why my stacked barchart becomes invisible.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

index = np.arange(degree_max+1)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize= (17,3.5))
axes[0].bar(index, average_Bias_squared, label='$E(bias^2)$')
axes[1].bar(index, average_Variance, color='orange', label='$E(variance)$')
axes[2].bar(index, average_Bias_squared, bottom=average_Variance, label='$E(bias^2)$')
```

The result come like this.
[Invisible Barchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7l8g.png)

Plz help! I want that invisible part back!

Comment: What does the `bottom` parameter indicate?

Comment: Could you post your full code (including values for the `average_…` variables you are plotting)? I cannot reproduce when I try creating this figure with approximated values.

Comment: @ScottHunter from [the matplotlib `Axes.bar` documentation:](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar.html) **bottom**: The y coordinate(s) of the bars bases.

Comment: To obtain stacked bars, you need to draw them on the same `ax`: `axes[2].bar(index, average_Variance)`, and  `axes[2].bar(index, average_Bias_squared, bottom=average_Variance)`.